# 2 Network Adapters - pass one through to a VM only

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I have 2 networks at home, on my Ubuntu server I want to connect the wired ethernet to the host machine, but then the wireless adapter of the device (which is connected to a different network) to a VM (virtual box) running on the host. However, I dont want the host to be able to use the wireless for network connectivity. As in I dont want to allow the host to be a bridge between the two networks.

Any ideas or thoughts on how I could set the set this up?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridge device with no IP address on it for the wireless adapter and select that bridged device when configuring the virtual machine.

If this is 'always on' you might want to look at KVM for your virtual machines as well, instead of virtual box, but that's a bit outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you! - I will try that - It is an always on VM for Home Assistant, I will check out KVM based on your advice. Thanks again.